# backbone.js View event handling

Tags: javascript, namespaces, backbone.js

I just started playing around with backbone.js and am enjoying the quirks of using it.
However am trying to use it for handling events in views for a site am working on.
Am also using namespaces to organise my code

```
    var App = App || {};
    App.Views = App.Views || {};
    App.Views.Sidebar = Backbone.View.extend({
                el:  '#app-wrapper',

                events : {
                    "click #rf":"test"
    ;           },

                test: function(e) {
                    alert("testing");
                }
            })
        }
  });
```

Heres the html, its just a skeleton of the site

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shopping List</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="underscore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="backbone.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    App.Views.Sidebar;
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="app-wrapper">

    <div id="app-header">
        <ul>
            <li id="rf">Test</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

However this snippet doesn't seem to work, the test() method is not called when click the #rf element.
Am doing something wrong, am pretty new to this.

Comment: needs more context, how do you render your view, what does your html look like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not instantiated your view. Try something like this:

```
var myView = new App.Views.Sidebar();
```

(instead of: `App.Views.Sidebar;` )

Also don't forget to instantiate your views once the document has been loaded. Something like this (if you use JQuery):

```
$(function() {

  // Initialize Backbone views.
  var myView = new App.Views.Sidebar();

});
```